# Gender neutral form of Arbeitgeber (employer)

Tags: gender, gender-neutrality

In the sentence

> Laut Arbeitnehmererfindungsgesetz (ArbnErfG)  besteht die Verpflichtung **den Arbeitgeber** unverzüglich in Schriftform zu informieren, wenn während des Arbeitsverhältnisses eine Erfindung gemacht wurde.
>
> (translates to "According to Employee Invention Act (ArbnErfG) the obligation exists to  inform the employer immediately in writing if an invention was made during the employment relationship.")

I am not sure if "der Arbeitgeber" is gender-neutral. Does Arbeitgeber in this case mean some official of the company? So if the owner of the company is female, would I have to write "die Arbeitgeberin"? But what if it is a really big company and the employee was employed by some male HR person, would it then be "der Arbeitgeber" or "die Arbeitgeberin"? Is "Arbeitgeber" a word that means the person that actively gives work to employees, or can I use it as a general term for a company where it is irrelevant if there work only women, it's gender is male nevertheless?

A workaround for this problem is to replace the word "Arbeitgeber" completely, but I am not satisfied with the suggestions made by [this website](https://geschicktgendern.de/):

> Arbeitgeber (sg.) Führungskraft
>
> Arbeitgeber (pl.) Arbeitgebende; Betriebe; Unternehmen

My mother tongue is German and I feel that "Arbeitgeber" is more of a general term, but I'd like some explanation and suggestions.

Comment: When we start "gendering" Arbeitgeber (--> Arbeitgeber/in), which is understood to be an organisation, not a person, we are not far away from gendering *Tisch* --> *Tisch/in* and *Mond* --> *Mond/in*. In this case I would vote for dismissing gender forms at all and only use *das*.  We had an orthography reform, we also can have a genus reform.

Comment: @Christian I know what you mean and it feels wrong for me, too. But then a new question arises: if "Arbeitgeber" is gender-neutral, what about "Arbeitnehmer" (employee), as this usually refers to a single person and not a anonymous organisation? The word is very similar. Would you gender this? (edit: as I just saw the edit to jonathans answer I guess this question is now sufficiently answered)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann This is just a matter of opinion. I'd say: Let's see where the evolution of language will lead us. I think, there is a significant difference between `Arbeitgeber` and `Tisch`: `Arbeitgeber` is a position of power, thus, within a mindset of gender-sensitive language as a means of feminism, there is an interest of de-masculinizing it as a concept. I don't see how this applies to `Tisch`.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   I agree with you regarding the position of power. The problem is perhaps, that *Arbeitgeber* sometimes is an anonymous (not gender bearing) organisation, sometimes it is a person (then usually gender-bearing), and sometimes it is an organisation dominated by persons of a certain gender-selfawarenss and behavioural pattern...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann In Austria, while "Arbeitgeber" is more common, it is at least not unheard of to call companies (*die* Gesellschaft) "Arbeitgeberin" in official contexts. (Sorry for the 3 edits in rapid succession).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arbeitgeber` does not denote a person in the company, but the company itself, understood as a legal person (juristische Person). So, if you work at, say, Siemens, your Arbeitgeber is not Joe Kaeser nor any other person working at Siemens, but just Siemens.

The gender-neutral form of `Arbeitgeber` which is used by people looking for gender-sensitive language is indeed `Arbeitgebende`, in analogy to `Studierende`. The website of the Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend suggests, they are using it as an official term: https://www.bmfsfj.de/bmfsfj/themen/gleichstellung/frauen-und-arbeitswelt/lohngerechtigkeit/entgelttransparenzgesetz/informationen-fuer-arbeitgebende

Google result suggest, though, that the use of `Arbeitgeber` (~50 Mio hits) is far more widespread than `Arbeitgebende` (~100k hits).

The analogous counterpart, `Arbeitnehmende`, is already part of the Duden, in the explanation of the Lemma `Wochenarbeitszeit` (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wochenarbeitszeit). The ratio of Google hits, (~20 Mio for `Arbeitnehmer` and ~150k for `Arbeitnehmende`) , also suggests a strong preference for the traditional masculine form, but shows a significantly higher share of the gender-neutral form compared to the ration between `Arbeitgeber` and `Arbeitgebende`. This difference could, I'd speculate, have its source in the fact that `Arbeitnehmer` are actual persons, which might emphasize the (felt) need for gender-neutral language more than in the case of the merely legal persons.

Comment: +1 exactly what I was looking for. I didn't see your edit before I wrote the comment asking for "Arbeitnehmer", but now you even cover this quite obvious follow-up question!